# split string with matching list in prolog

Tags: split, prolog, dcg

I want split string into sub string using dcg list.
here my code
`any(S, K) --> {member(S,K)}, S.`
`pre(S) --> any(S, ["di","tri","tetre"]).`
`split([])     --> "".`
`split([X|Xs]) --> pre(X), split(Xs).`

`?- phrase(split(Ls), "tridi").`
`Ls = [[t, r, i], [d, i]]`
Here some error.it is split as letters,expected answer is
`?- phrase(split(Ls), "tridi").`
`Ls = [tri,di].`
 Any Idea for this problem?

Comment: The problem is that you are confusing the different datatypes that your program uses. Code lists, char lists, strings, atoms.... This is admittedly one of Prolog's common gotchas, as you don't have to declare types in any way. Also, this `pre --> any` and `member` thing that you are doing is what I would call a "code smell".

Comment: And are you showing the full program? What Prolog implementation are you using? What version? Are you setting some global flag by any chance?

Comment: In this program `pre --> any` has all list elements are string or atom.The main problem is query input is String that String is split like `Ls = [tri,di].` or `Ls = ["tri","di"].`.I am using SWI-Prolog Version 7.1.17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for SWI-Prolog v.7, you need to change your code like

```
any(A,K) --> {member(S,K)}, S, {atom_codes(A, S)}.
pre(S) --> any(S, [`di`,`tri`,`tetre`]).
split([])     --> "".
split([X|Xs]) --> pre(X), split(Xs).
```

and then

```
?- phrase(split(Ls), `tridi`).
Ls = [tri, di]
```

Note I added a conversion to any//1. The rationale of string representation is [documented here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=strings).

With your original code and query:

```
?- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, codes).
true.

?- phrase(split(Ls), "tridi").
Ls = [tri, di]
```